# Unix shell script using Expect shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, expect

Im writing a script to collect micro code levels for adapters on each servers in AIX, using Expect shell.

```
#!/bin/ksh
for hostname in ABCD123 ABCD234 ABCD445
do
expect << 'EOS'
set hos {$hostname}
spawn ssh padmin@$hostname
expect "Password:"
send "ABC1234\n"
expect "$"
send "oem_setup_env\n"
expect "#"
send "lsmcode -A | sed -e 's/^/$hos: /'\n"
expect "#"
send "exit\n"
expect "$"
send "exit\n"
EOS
done
```

But unfortunately the script fails to run. Can you please help me

Output should be like this

```
ABCD123 : sys0!system:CL320_040 (t) CL320_040 (p) CL320_040 (t)
ABCD123 : ent0!14101103.CN0110
ABCD123 : ent1!14101103.CN0110
ABCD123 : ent2!14101103.CN0110
ABCD123 : ent3!14101103.CN0110
ABCD123 : ent4!14108802.DV0210
```

Comment: for hostname in ABCD123 ABCD234 ABCD445
do 
expect << 'EOS' 
set hos {$hostname} 
spawn ssh padmin@$hostname 
expect "Password:" 
send "ABC1234\n" 
expect "$" 
send "oem_setup_env\n" 
expect "#" 
send "lsmcode -A | sed -e 's/^/$hos: /'\n" 
expect "#" 
send "exit\n" 
expect "$" 
send "exit\n" 
EOS 
done

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with only shell code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a quoted heredoc, the shell does not expand the shell variable `$hostname`. Do this: pass the variable to expect via the environment

```
export hostname
for hostname in ABCD123 ABCD234 ABCD445
do
    expect << 'EOS'
        set hos $env(hostname) ;# access the environment variable
        spawn ssh padmin@$hos
        expect "Password:"
        send "ABC1234\r"
        expect "$"
        send "oem_setup_env\r"
        expect "#"
        send "lsmcode -A | sed -e 's/^/$hos: /'\r"
        expect "#"
        send "exit\r"
        expect "$"
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof             ;# wait for the connection to close
EOS
done
```

Idiomatically, you use `\r` to "hit enter" for the send commands.

Comment: it didnt pick up that variable could you advise if any possibility.can't read "env(hostname)": no such variable
    while executing

Comment: @glenn jackman How to suppress the output to the terminal before successfully logins the telnet?

Comment: 2 things: `spawn -noecho` and `log_user 0` -- `log_user 1` to re-enable output to the terminal.